# Contact form data in Rails 5 form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, email

I'm having one of those moments. My problem is probably simple but I'm not getting it figured out.

I have a Rails 5 app that I'm developing. It contains a contact form for the contact to fill out and submit.

Next I have ActionMailer set to send an email to the Contact informing them that their message was received and is being reviewed. I also have ActionMailer set to send an email to the website admin that is supposed to contain the contact form data. This is where I am running into a problem. How do I pass the contact form data into my email view?

Here is the contacts_controller:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_contact, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /contacts
  # GET /contacts.

  def index
    @contacts = Contact.all
  end

  # GET /contacts/1
  # GET /contacts/1.json
  def show
  end



  # GET /contacts/new
  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  # GET /contacts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /contacts
  # POST /contacts.json
  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @contact.save


        FormMailer.message_received(@contact).deliver_now 
        FormMailer.new_web_message(@email).deliver_now
        format.html { redirect_to thank_you_path, notice: 'Your message was sent.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @contact }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end



  # PATCH/PUT /contacts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /contacts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @contact.update(contact_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @contact, notice: 'Contact was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @contact }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /contacts/1
  # DELETE /contacts/1.json
  def destroy
    @contact.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to contacts_url, notice: 'Contact was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_contact
      @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def contact_params
      params.require(:contact).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :vehicle_type, :tire_size, :current_tire, :phone_number, :email, :message)
    end
end
```

The Mailer:

```
    class FormMailer < ApplicationMailer

  # Subject can be set in your I18n file at config/locales/en.yml
  # with the following lookup:
  #
  #   en.form_mailer.message_received.subject
  #
  def message_received(contact)
    @contact = contact
    @url = 'http://example.com'
    @greeting = "Hello"


    mail(to: @contact.email, subject: 'Thanks for contacting Halstead Tire LLC')

  end
  def new_web_message


    @greeting = "Hello"
    @email = '<mymail@gmail.com>'
    @website = 'http://www.example.com'



    mail(to: @email, subject: 'A new message from your website.' )
  end



end
```

The view new_web_message.html.erb:

```
<h1><%= @greeting %> Nathan,</h1>

<p>
  Someone's requested some information from your site. Please go to <%= @website %> to get the details.
</p>
<body>

</body>
```

I have the emails sending correctly and they are delivering as expected. The message for the Contact is working perfectly. I would like to have the Admin*(new_web_message)* email take the Contact's information and send it. How do I pass those values into the view? I want to take all the contact_params*(from contacts_controller)* and put them in the email to the admin. I realize this might be a simple and silly mistake but I can't figure it out. Is it possible to do this all in one mailer or do i need to have separate mailers for the contact and the admin*(new_web_message)*? *As i said the emails are working fine set up in one Mailer right now but I just need to get the data from the form passed into the admin**(new_web_message)* email.

In the Contact email it works to access the data like so as is obvious in the mailer:

```
@contact.email
@contact.phone_number
@contact.message
```

and so forth. Why doesn't this same theory work in the Admin email??

Does my mailer need to be named the same as the controller?(contacts_mailer) instead of (FormMailer) as i have it named now?

Thanks!

EDIT:

So I implemented Ryan's code in my app but now I get:

```
 NoMethodError in Contacts#create
```

Here is the new_web_message.html.erb

```
    <h1><%= @greeting %> Nathan,</h1>

<p>
  Someone's requested some information from your site. Please go to <%=     @website %> to get the details.
</p>
<body>
<p><%= @contact.first_name %></p>
<p><%= @contact.last_name %></p>

</body>
```

Here is the error shown when i submit the form:

```
Showing /Users/evan/htire/app/views/form_mailer/new_web_message.html.erb where line #7 raised:

undefined method `first_name' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #7):


</p>
<body>
<p><%= @contact.first_name %></p> (line 7)
<p><%= @contact.last_name %></p> (line 8)

</body>
```

Apparently I need to define methods somewhere but I'm running out of ideas. (yes I'm kinda new at rails)

Here's the model contact.rb

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord

    def new_web_message
        first_name = first_name
        last_name = last_name

    end


        attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name, :vehicle_type, :tire_size, :current_tire, :phone_number, :email, :message  



    validates_presence_of :first_name
    validates_presence_of :last_name
    validates_presence_of :phone_number
    validates_presence_of :message

end
```

The updated mailer using Ryan's suggestion:

```
class FormMailer < ApplicationMailer

  # Subject can be set in your I18n file at config/locales/en.yml
  # with the following lookup:
  #
  #   en.form_mailer.message_received.subject
  #
  def message_received(contact)
    @contact = contact
    @url = 'http://halsteadtire.net'
    @greeting = "Hello"


    mail(to: @contact.email, subject: 'Thanks for contacting Halstead Tire LLC')

  end
  def new_web_message(contact, params)
    @contact = contact

    @greeting = "Hello"
    @email = '<halsteadtire1@gmail.com>'
    @website = 'http://www.halsteadtire.net/contacts'


    mail(to: @email, subject: 'A new message from your website.' )
  end



end
```

Updated controller using Ryan's code:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_contact, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /contacts
  # GET /contacts.json
  def index
    @contacts = Contact.all
  end

  # GET /contacts/1
  # GET /contacts/1.json
  def show
  end



  # GET /contacts/new
  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  # GET /contacts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /contacts
  # POST /contacts.json
  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @contact.save


        FormMailer.message_received(@contact).deliver_now 
        FormMailer.new_web_message(@email, params).deliver_now
        format.html { redirect_to thank_you_path, notice: 'Your message was sent.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @contact }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end



  # PATCH/PUT /contacts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /contacts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @contact.update(contact_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @contact, notice: 'Contact was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @contact }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /contacts/1
  # DELETE /contacts/1.json
  def destroy
    @contact.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to contacts_url, notice: 'Contact was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_contact
      @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def contact_params
      params.require(:contact).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :vehicle_type, :tire_size, :current_tire, :phone_number, :email, :message)
    end
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pass parameters into `new_web_message`. Change your method to:

```
def new_web_message(contact)
  @contact = contact
  #rest of your code
end
```

And then call is using this:

```
FormMailer.new_web_message(@contact).deliver_now
```

If you want ALL the params (i.e. even the ones you aren't saving to `Contact`), just add it as an additional param:

```
def new_web_message(contact, params)
  ...
end
```

And

```
FormMailer.new_web_message(@email, params).deliver_now
```

Disclaimer: I don't know if this works in Rails 5 (it should), but this would work in Rails 4.2.